# Java applet doesn't run in AdoptOpenJDK

Tags: java, applet

Several years ago, I wrote a Java applet that runs in the browser, and runs executables (Exceed XStart files) which are hosted on a network share. The users can manually run the XStart files themselves, but it's a hassle they don't need.

Recently, I installed AdoptOpenJDK on my PC (we were using Oracle's JDK), and now the applet no longer runs in the browser. Some quick googling revealed that AdoptOpenJDK apparently doesn't support java applets.

Oracle JDK isn't an option (company is dropping it). Java Web Start or JNLP won't work (AdoptOpenJDK doesn't support them either looks like). IcedTea looked promising, but doesn't work in IE; which is a must as it's the company standard.

Is there a workaround for this? What's the preferred way of accessing local resources inside a browser?

Comment: You might have to translate the logic to something that runs a proper web server (e.g. Spring boot)... Applets will basically not be supported by any Java distribution

Comment: Java applets have been a legacy technology for a decade (if not longer, the iphone for example has **never** supported them). Applets are (now) dead. Time to migrate to a new technology.

Comment: I suggest you read the [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) white paper of 2018-03 by Oracle. And read [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no formal workaround to getting a Java applet to work in a browser, because [all major browsers have ripped out the NPAPI support needed](https://superuser.com/a/748477/169038) to have the Java applet work.

Also, the Java applet itself was *particularly* singled out to the degree that [Oracle decided that it wasn't going to pursue applet functionality in Java 9](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

The logical way forward would be to find an old browser to run this with, but I would argue that this is worse, since now you're having to straddle old technology with new and existing infrastructure, which may lead to *more* frustration.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Do you know if there's any other client side technology that allows websites to access local files?  Granted, I'm asking for a huge security hole, but that's the current requirements of my website.  If it's just not do-able . . . well that's unfortunate too.  I guess I could try porting the applet to a desktop application.

Comment: @Eren You need to bundle a Java implementation with your app. So you need a build of your app for every deployment target ( macOS, Windows, Linux, etc.).